# A way to display an array of objects in reverse?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, angularfire

I can't seem to display the items sorted here in reverse order. I want to display the last item added to the list at the top instead of the bottom:

Weeks appear in descending order (correctly) but items do not. I'm also using a compare to move completed tasks to the bottom.

```
app.directive('repeatByWeek', function($parse, $window) {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    transclude: true,
    template: '<div ng-transclude></div>',
    link: function(scope, el, attrs) {
      // get the global moment lib
      var moment = $window.moment;
      scope.weeks = [];
      updateList();
      // whenever the source collection changes, update our nested list
      scope.list.$watch(updateList);
      scope.$watch(function(){
        return scope.list;
      }, updateList);
      function compare(a, b) {
         return a.completeTime - b.completeTime;
      }
      function updateList() {
        scope.list.$loaded().then(function(){
          scope.list.sort(compare);
          scope.weeks = sortItems(parseItems(scope.list));
        });
      }
      function sortItems(sets) {
        var items = [];
        // get a list of weeks and sort them
        var weeks = sortDescending(Object.keys(sets));
         for(var i=0, wlen=weeks.length; i < wlen; i++) {
           var w = weeks[i];
           // get a list of days and sort them
           var days = Object.keys(sets[w]);
           var weekEntry = {
             time: w,
             days: []
           };
           items.push(weekEntry);
           // now iterate the days and add entries
           for(var j=0, dlen=days.length; j < dlen; j++) {
             var d = days[j];
             weekEntry.days.push({
               time: d,
               // here is the list of tasks from parseItems
               items: sets[w][d]
             });
           }
         }
        //  console.log('sortItems', items);
        return items;
      }
      // take the array and nest it in an object by week and then day
      function parseItems(list) {
        var sets = {};
        angular.forEach(list, function(item) {
           var week = moment(item.$priority).startOf('week').valueOf();
           var day = moment(item.$priority).startOf('day').valueOf();
           if( !sets.hasOwnProperty(week) ) {
             sets[week] = {};
           }
           if( !sets[week].hasOwnProperty(day) ) {
             sets[week][day] = [];
           }
           sets[week][day].push(item);
         });
        //  console.log('parseItems', sets);
         return sets;
      }
      function sortDescending(list) {
        return list.sort().reverse();
      }
    }
  };
});
```

Any advice would be much appreciated? I've tried various ways of adding "reverse()" to the list but that doesn't seem to work.

Tried to far:

sortDescending(items)
scope.items.reverse()
scope.items.sort().reverse()

Can I push them on in reverse? Am I messing up the sort with the compare?

Comment: ... Use the `.reverse()` function on the array, then use the same display code?

Comment: I've tried that in various forms and places. Doesn't seem to work. It might be because the specific level I need to reverse is too deeply nested?

Comment: reverse simply reverses an array. If you have `var arr = [obj1, obj2, obj3]; arr.reverse();` then arr will be [3,2,1]

Comment: scope.list.sort(compare).reverse(); works! Thanks. Previously I was trying to reverse it separately but along with the sort and during the $watch worked.

Comment: on a code-constructive note: your `sortDescending` doesn't in any way guarantee a sort order. If you want certainty when sorting, use a comparator so you have `return list.sort(this.comparator).reverse();` with `comparator: function(a,b) { ... },`

Comment: The only problem now is that when I add a task it goes to the bottom of the list. I think I need to break apart some of this functionality. I need completed tasks to go to the bottom of one list but to the top of another.

Comment: code is datastructures. Once you run into problems like this, it's a clear indication you're not using the right structure for your data. Write (or grab off the internet) an ordered list object instead, and start working with those rather than with plain arrays.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your reply. Looks like I need to do some more research.